# $_POST failing as opposed to $_REQUEST

Tags: php, ajax, post, request

I'm trying to switch form $_REQUEST to $_POST, as it is more secure.
I have the following code in my server.php:

```
    if (isset($_REQUEST['mode']) && $_REQUEST['mode']=='verwijderturf'){
    $sql="SELECT * FROM users WHERE Naam='".cleanInput($_REQUEST['naam'])."'";
    $result=mysql_query($sql);
    $count=mysql_num_rows($result);
    if($count > 0){
        $date2 = date("Y-m-d");
        $naam2 = cleanInput($_REQUEST['naam']);
        $door = cleanInput($_REQUEST['door']);
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO turfjes 
                     VALUES (
                             'Adtje', 
                             '".$naam2."',
                             '', 
                             '".$date2."',
                             '".$door."')") 
        or die (mysql_error());
    }
}
```

Which works perfectly.
However, when I switch all $_REQUEST's to $_POST my server.php does not do anything...

I'm using ajax requests to send data to my server.
For example:

```
function verwijderturf() {
    var naam = $("naam").value;
    $("naamnieuw").value = "";
    $("naam").value = "";
    $("redennieuw").value = "";
    new Ajax.Request('server.php?mode=verwijderturf&naam='+naam+'&door='+$("door2").value,{
        method: 'post', 
        onSuccess: update,
        onFailure: ajaxFailure
    });
}
```

As you can see, my ajax methode is 'post', so it should work just fine with $_POST.

Can anyone help me please?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to provide the parameters as POST parameters, not GET. Which Javascript library are you using?

I.e. for jQuery it would be

```
jQuery.ajax('server.php',{
    data: {
        'mode': 'verwijderturf',
        'naam': naam,
        'door': $("door2").value
    },
    type: 'post', 
    success: update,
    error: ajaxFailure
});
```

Example for Prototype:

```
new Ajax.Request('server.php',{
    parameters: {
        'mode': 'verwijderturf',
        'naam': naam,
        'door': $("door2").value
    },
    method: 'post', 
    onSuccess: update,
    onFailure: ajaxFailure
});
```

`data` (jQuery) and `parameters` (Prototype) is a key/value object and represents all POST parameters. In both librarys this could be a serialized string, like `'key=value&key2=value'` but i prefer to use an object and let the library serialize them.

Comment: Thank you very much for your accurate and quick reply, I did not know that. I can accept the answer in 8 minutes, which I will do.

Comment: Looks like he's using prototype

Comment: I am indeed using prototype, but why does that differ?

Comment: The name of the options and accepted data type of them depends on your framework/library. Prototype uses [`parameters`](http://prototypejs.org/api/ajax/options) and jQuery `data`.

Comment: Yes, I just realized that. Thanks for pointing that out. I have changed to jquery, as I use that in most files anyway.
Thanks again for pointing that out ;)

Comment: I've added an example for Prototype users now, just to complete the question. :)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, except is a simple HTML FORM with the POST method, and I'm not using any library so it has to be a standard instalation of linux/apache/php/mysql (php is version 5).

Maybe POST and REQUEST uses different libraries from PHP? Maybe no library is needed and it has to do with somo INI file? Who know, the fact is, $_POST array doesn't work.